# Reading Arduino data using WebSocket with HTML & nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, arduino

I can't quite grasp the last step in this puzzle. Everything compiles, and it is "bug-free". This is my first foray into communications/full-stack and I have been stumped despite numerous excellent tutorials.

- [WORKING] Arduino reads and interprets sensor data
- [WORKING] index.js acquires data with serial communication over USB
- [WORKING] index.js creates a WebSocket connection using nodejs
- [WORKING] index.html performs the WebSocket handshake
- [WORKING] index.html uses Plotly to create a real-time line graph
- *[WIP] index.html passes through the Arduino data in the Plotly function*

### Chopped down index.html:

```
        <script src="server/plotly.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            //connection to the web socket server
            const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000"); 
            let foo = 0.0;

            //working
            ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
                console.log("We Are Connected");
                ws.send("TestData");
            });

            //working
            ws.addEventListener("message", e => {
                console.log(e);
                console.log("Data Recieved! Success.");
            });
        </script>
```

Rest of the file is just the graphing function which I would like to pass through Arduino data.

### index.js

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 5000 });

//create a serial port that allows serial connection from Arduino
let SerialPort = require("serialport");
let port = new SerialPort('COM4', { baudRate: 9600 });

let Readline = require("@serialport/parser-readline");
let parser = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\n' }));

wss.on("connection", ws => {
    //working
    console.log("New Client Connection");

    //this is what I need to passthrough my Plotly arg
    parser.on("data", data => {
        //event is firing but can't get client to grab this. Console logs data correctly.
        console.log(RPM: ${data});     
    });

    //working on both ends
    ws.on("message", data => {
        console.log("TEST")
        ws.send(data);
    });

    //doesn't log?
     port.on("open", () => {
         console.log("Serial Port Open");
     });

});

//working
console.log("The server is ON");
```

I'm looking for a strategy or method to grab the sensor data in my HTML file. Is it something simple conceptually I am missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You established a websocket server, and it is works. If you want to send message to websocket, define a socket to the websocket server, get out the Serial part from websocket server, and run is standalone, and send data from this to the websocket.
Like this:

```
const http = require('http');
const WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(5000);
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

let SerialPort = require("serialport");
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM5", {
    baudRate: 9600,
    parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline("\n")
});

var connection;

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
      console.log('Received Message:', message.utf8Data);
      connection.sendUTF('Hi this is WebSocket server!');
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log('Client has disconnected.');
    });
    
});

serialPort.on('open',function(){
        //connection.sendUTF('Hi this is WebSocket server!');
        console.log('open');
        serialPort.on('data', function(data){
                readData = data.toString();
                console.log("N<", readData);
                if( typeof connection!="undefined")
                connection.sendUTF( readData); 

        });
});
```